# How do I increment tuples in an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, tuples, increment

I'm trying to create this map where you can move North, South, East, and West for a Python text adventure project. The problem is I can't seem to figure out how to change the coordinates or if I'm even doing any of this correctly.

```
map_array = [
    [(1, 5), (2, 5), (3, 5), (4, 5), (5, 5)],
    [(1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 4), (4, 4), (5, 4)],
    [(1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3), (4, 3), (5, 3)],
    [(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 2), (5, 2)],
    [(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1)]
]
starting_point = map_array[2][2]


def show_map():
    for row in map_array:
        print('\n' + str(row))

show_map()

def explore(player_coordinates):
    print(f"Current player coordinates are {player_coordinates}.")
    update_player_coordinates = input("Where do you go? ")
    if update_player_coordinates.lower == 'east':
        player_coordinates += [1][1]
        return player_coordinates
    explore(player_coordinates)

explore(starting_point)
```

I am trying to make it so that when I type a cardinal direction it will increment player_coordinates by the space. So far I just get this:

Current player coordinates are (3, 3).
Where do you go? east
Current player coordinates are (3, 3).
Where do you go?

It should be (4, 3)

Comment: You want `.lower()` with parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Tuples are, by nature, immutable. If you'd like a mutable version you'd have to use a list.

```
current_position = [3, 3]
if update_player_coordinates.lower() == "east":
    current_position[0] += 1

print(current_position)
> [4, 3]
```

Alternatively, you would have to reconstruct and reassign the tuple

```
current_position = (3, 3)
if update_player_coordinates.lower() == "east":
    current_position = current_position[0] + 1, current_position[1]

print(current_position)
> (4, 3)
```

Comment: Perhaps out of scope, but it might be worth adding bounds checking (i.e. make sure that moving east is allowed)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you actually want to increment the items in `map_array` at all -- you just want to keep track of *which* map square the player is currently in.

So you might want something like this:

```
# start the player at location 2,2 in the map
player_x = 2
player_y = 2

...
if update_player_coordinates.lower == 'east':
    # player_y stays the same 
    player_x += 1
```

Although if you do this, then you probably don't need to store the coordinates in `map_array` at all, because `player_x, player_y` would now be your coordinates.